# Using range slices to create mutable disjoint slices, and returning them from a function

Tags: rust

In the main function below I use range slices to create a mutable reference to an element in the slice (`numbers[i]`) and an iterator of references to the other values. This is okay because the borrow checker is smart enough to look at the range notation and check that the slices are disjoint, so the borrow rules are not violated for any individual item in the slice.

I have tried to factor this out into a function, however when I return these values I get an error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    for i in 0..numbers.len() {
        let other_values = numbers[..i]
        .iter()
        .chain(numbers[i+1..].iter());
        let sum: i32 = other_values.sum();
        numbers[i] += sum;
    }

    println!("{:?}", numbers);
}

fn split<'a>(s: &'a mut [u32], i: usize) -> (&'a mut u32, impl Iterator<Item=&'a u32>){
    let r = s[..i]
    .iter()
    .chain(s[i+1..].iter());
    (&mut s[i], r)
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s[_]` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:20:6
   |
16 | fn split<'a>(s: &'a mut [u32], i: usize) -> (&'a mut u32, impl Iterator<Item=&'a u32>){
   |          -- lifetime `'a` defined here
17 |     let r = s[..i]
   |             - immutable borrow occurs here
...
20 |     (&mut s[i], r)
   |     -^^^^^^^^^----
   |     ||
   |     |mutable borrow occurs here
   |     returning this value requires that `*s` is borrowed for `'a`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut).

Comment: I'm aware of this method, but thought the range slice notation is nicer and may be more performant. As I want the data before and after `i`, I would need to use a combo of split_at_mut and split_first_mut, and then chain them. This seems like a lot for what should be a simple algorithm.

Comment: Why would one be more or less performant than the other? Brackets are just syntax sugar for `Index(Mut)::index(_mut)`

Answer (score 2):

> This is okay because the borrow checker is smart enough to look at the range notation and check that the slices are disjoint

It's not, the borrow checker is able to partially borrow structures, but not collections, not even slices.

The first snippet consumes the iterator (and thus releases the shared borrow) before a mutable borrow is needed. If you add a

```
let n = &mut numbers[i];
```

before the sum, you'll get a borrow error. Same as `split` and for the same reasons.

> This seems like a lot for what should be a simple algorithm.

It's the same thing except working:

```rust
fn split(s: &mut [u32], i: usize) -> (&mut u32, impl Iterator<Item=&u32>){
    let (h, t) = s.split_at_mut(i);
    let (e, t) = t.split_first_mut().unwrap();
    (e, h.iter().chain(t.iter()))
}
```